# RStudio and Microsoft R-Open

Tags: r, rstudio, microsoft-r

I currently have R-statistics distribution working with RStudio.

I want to install also the Microsoft R-Open version, but how do I get RStudio to 
reference this MRO distribution and not the 'regular' R-statistics.

I could not find any documentation on this either here on Stack Overflow or on RStudio's website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you want to run RStudio against the Microsoft R Open version you have installed?

If so, in RStudio, go to Tools | Global Options and you will be presented with the Options dialog. Choose "General" on the right hand side and at the top you see "R version:". Click change and you will get the"Choose R Installation" dialog, where you now choose the MRO version, as per below:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Niels, Thanks for you input! This is it! This is what i was looking for!

Comment: I will mark down your reply as the answer. Thanks again!